# GP conform to mesh

Tags: mesh, grease-pencil

How can I take the grease pencil drawing I have and apply it to the shape of a mesh I have.  In other words, how can I make it follow the surface of a mesh?
Thx.

**follow-up on comments**

[image: front]
Here's from front

[image: side]
Here's from the side.  It tends to change form as you change angle and zoom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the stroke placement option to 'surface' like this:

[image]

To increase strokes accuracy you can change these two options, 'input samples' and 'active smooth':

[image]

You can also lower the stroke thickness here but will stay some kind of cylinder even if smaller radius:

[image]

Comment: I'm having trouble finding that dropdown.  What do you have selected?  Can you help me find it?

Comment: Ope, I figured it out.  You have to go to draw mode, and you have to have the object visible in order for this to work.  Just curious, do you know how to make it follow the shape of one object when the object isn't visible?

Comment: After adding a GP object, add a layer, then use 'draw' mode (upper left of the 3D view or ctrl+tab then 'draw') and this option will be available

Comment: Ahh, got a problem.  It appears that since it's right against the mesh, it's causing it to have troulbe deciding which one to display.  Know the answer?

Comment: isn't visible? mean H? I don't think that can work if hidden.

Comment: Nevermind then.  The problem I'm having is that when it conforms to the shape, it gets distorted and jagged.  How can I keep it smooth?

Comment: If several objects, GP will extrapolate in between... or you mean something else?

Comment: About distorted and jagged, can you add a picture of what you mean?

Comment: yeah, just a sec.

Comment: But no, about your edit, I don't know

Comment: That's too bad.  Hopefully I'll figure it out.

Comment: But this bad effect is due to overlapping between strokes and the mesh, not the stroke itself. That means, things depend on what you want to do with meshes and strokes...

Comment: That's right.  Is there a distance setting I can change?

Comment: Consider to upvote @RBlong2us takes a lot of effort making that gifs for you...

Comment: Yes, "offset" from the "stroke placement" option shown in the answer.

Comment: Thanks @brockmann, and RBlong2us... UV is not the only goal, but ok, thanks.

Comment: No, Thank you!  I've got my problems answered!  Thank you!